# Creating bigger controlled nots from single qubit, Toffoli, and CNOT gates, without workspace

Tags: quantum-computing, circuits

Exercise 4.29 from [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107002176) has me stumped.

> Find a circuit containing $O(n^2)$ Toffoli, CNOT and single qubit gates which implements a $C^n(X)$ gate (for $n > 3$), using no work qubits.

I've figured out that [this can't be done classically](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40864/is-it-possible-to-make-n-way-controlled-nots-out-of-toffoli-gates-without-extra).

I've figured out how to do it with $O(2^n)$ exponentially precise gates (nest the double-control-from-single-controls-and-square-root-of-operation construction inside itself $n-2$ times).

I've tried generalizing the above construction into accumulating a linear combination of controlled operations. For example, if I have 3 controls called A and B and C and make a vector of the various cases [0, A, B, C, AB, BC, AC, ABC] then:

- Applying an operation unconditionally adds [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
- Controlling an operation on A adds [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
- Xoring A into C then controlling an operation on C (then undoing the xor) would add [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
- Xoring (A and B) into C via a toffoli gate then controlling an operation on C would add [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

Then I would try to add (apply a root of X) and subtract (apply inverse square root) the various vectors I can make until the result comes out as [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, N].

But I keep hitting various walls, such as solutions ending up with large multiples (i.e. the gates I'm using become exponentially precise, which I think is a no-no) or just not being able to solve the system due to the interplay between generating elements with AND/XOR then solving with +/* being non-standard or creating exponential numbers of gates.

What are some other approaches to try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I ended up solving this for $O(n)$ gates. I wrote up a trilogy of blog posts on it.

1. [Constructing Large Controlled Nots (classically, with an ancilla)](http://algorithmicassertions.com/circuits/2015/06/05/Constructing-Large-Controlled-Nots.html)
2. [Constructing Large Increments (classically, with an ancilla)](http://algorithmicassertions.com/circuits/2015/06/12/Constructing-Large-Increment-Gates.html)
3. [Using Quantum Gates instead of Ancilla Bits](http://algorithmicassertions.com/circuits/2015/06/22/Using-Quantum-Gates-instead-of-Ancilla-Bits.html)

Of course it would suck if you found this twenty years from now and my website was long gone, so the basic steps follow in quickly-described image form.

## 1. Bootstrap a Borrowable Ancilla Bit

Use a square root and its inverse to reduce the maximum number of controls  by one, creating an uninvolved wire for each operation. Then iteratively move controls off of non-Not operations, and re-arrange the cruft that results into large increment gates and single-qubit phase gates.

[image: Bootstrapping an Ancilla Bit]

## 2. Use Single Ancilla Bit to Cut Operations in Half

For each large operation, use the uninvolved wire as a borrowed ancilla bit. Use it to transform the huge increment and controlled-not gates into smaller operations that each have approximately half of the wires uninvolved. Repeat twice, if required for the next step to have enough working space.

[image: Halving Size of Controlled-Not with Ancilla]

[image: Halving Size of Incrementer with Ancilla]

## 3. Use Many Ancilla Bits to Finish

For each still-too-large operation, borrow the many uninvolved wires as ancilla bits. Use them to get all the way down to Toffoli-or-smaller gates.

[image: Reducing Controlled-Not to Toffolis]

[image: Reducing Incrementer to Toffolis]

Those three steps will get you all the way from a fully-controlled-not to linearly many Toffoli, CNOT, and single-qubit gates. There's a few implied pieces, like how to merge a control into an increment gate, but they're pretty simple.

(Sorry for the inconsistent style of the diagrams.)